# How to give access to delete his own comments

Tags: 7, users, comments

I am using Drupal 7 and want user should be able to delete his own comment. I know that is it not supported by drupal 7 due to threading. 
You can provide edit permission from "admin/people/permissions" but there is no option to provide permission of delete.

Thanks in Advance

Ref : https://www.drupal.org/node/777696

Comment: I think `Edit own comments` permission also gives the option to delete the comment.

Comment: @SumitMadan: no. Edit own comment does not provide permission for deleting. Check link provided in post.

Comment: If the users have a comment and a thread with lots of comments replying **that particular comment** what are you going to do with the thread? delete them as well? This will create very user unfriendly scenario, so, its not supported by default.

Comment: @JhilkeDai: Right now i am not bother about thread. I may disable threading from admin.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with coding? You can try this [tutorial](https://www.adammalone.net/post/allowing-anonymous-comment-deletion-rights%20/).

edit: and i ran into [this site](http://planken.org/2014/11/drupal-7x-allow-users-delete-their-own-comments%20/), wich is a patch to the module 'Comment Goodness'. There's also some extra info about flat comments (the default structure is nested, not flat).

Answer (score 0):

Are you building a site with registered users? If not, you could check out https://disqus.com/ , I used that on the site I'm building after I discovered they also have a drupal module. It provides users with the ability to delete their own comments as well. LevelUpTuts (YouTube) made a tutorial about the installation and configuration.